# spring dependency injection, child projects to provide interface implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have  parent spring java project that has a spring component:

```
@Component
public class MyJobRunner {

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private MyMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public MyJobRunner (JobLauncher jobLauncher, MyMapper mapper) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.mapper= mapper;
    }
```

Then I have separate projects that import this parent project as dependency and use the above class. These separate project need to provide implementation of the `MyMapper` interface which should be annotated with `@Component`.

The issue I have is my Parent project main application fails as I have no implementation so cannot autowire.

other than providing a default implementation in the parent project, is there a way I can get the application up and running? What if i provide a default implementation in parent project but without `@Component`.

The question is raised because the above is forcing me to add `@Primary` on all separate projects to override the `DefaultMapper` implementation in parent project and ideally I want to avoid `@Primary` as some may forget to annotate it.

```
//parent project 
@Component
public class DefaultMapper implements MyMapper {...}

//projectA
@Primary
@Component
public class ProjectAMapper implements MyMapper {...}

//projectB
@Primary
@Component
public class ProjectBMapper implements MyMapper {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to annotate your `DefaultMapper` with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyMapper.class)`. Then Spring will create `DefaultMapper` only if no another implementations of `MyMapper` contained in `BeanFactory`.

Comment: putting this annotation directly on the implementation class does not work. perhaps only way is with `@Bean` in a config class

Comment: I have tested both variants (annotate class and method) and they both worked. Just need to pay attention to beans declaration order in config class. Spring must not instantiate default implementation first.